# regexp for HTML java

Tags: java, regex

Im trying to made a regex , but i waste  a lot of time and cannot be sucessufully, Here is my input and output expected.

Input:

```
 <table>
 <tr>
     <td colspan="4" class="fundo_subtitulo">MAX 250</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   ANY DATA
 </tr>
 <tr>
   ANY DATA
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>MAX 400</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   ANY DATA
 </tr>

<table>
```

Expected Output

find()

```
     <tr>
       <td colspan="4" class="fundo_subtitulo">MAX 250</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       ANY DATA
     </tr>
     <tr>
       ANY DATA
     </tr>
```

next

```
     <tr>
        <td>MAX 400</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       ANY DATA
     </tr>
```

Conditions:
- Word start with MAX.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<tr>\\s+<td colspan=\".*?\" class=\".*?\">MAX \\d+</td>\\s+</tr>");
```

***DEMO:***
http://fiddle.re/z77dp

Comment: But if i want to get the first "tr" and the last "tr"?

Comment: @Makoton I've updated the answer, check it out.

Comment: I'm using for test : http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: Check the demo at regexplanet http://fiddle.re/z77dp

Comment: Thanks work fine only one more help i have to ignore inside <td> could you remove for regex?

Comment: I cannot understand you, please update your question with the desired output.

Comment: I update my answer look that.